# Rest-сервис. Проблема получения данных в веб-запросе

Tags: java, spring, rest

Поставлена задача, с веб-сервиса вытащить JSON-массив, а затем его обработать.
По идее, технология Rest, должна выводить в браузере String, но этого не происходит.

Вопросы:

Неправильная конфигурация в RequestMapping или в теле метода нужно еще что-то прописать?

В чем моя недоработка?

Вот вариант кода:

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class Places {
    /*OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String a;*/

    @RequestMapping(value = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Place", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"Content-Type = application/json", "X-Parse-Application-Id = /*my app-id*/", "X-Parse-REST-API-Key = /*my app-secret*/"})
    public String getting(){
        /*Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Place")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "app-id")
                .addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "app-secret")
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        a = response.body().string();

        return a;*/
        return "getting";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аннотация `@RequestMapping` говорит Spring-у, что отмеченный ей метод будет обрабатывать HTTP запрос от внешнего клиента. У вас же в этой аннотации указаны параметры чужого сервера и заголовки, как будто вы подразумевали подключение вашего сервера к другому серверу по HTTP.

Поле `value` должно указывать относительный путь на **вашем** сервере, который будет обрабатываться этим методом.

В поле `headers` указываются названия заголовков (без значений), которые должны присутствовать, чтобы запрос был обработан. Сами значения можно передать в метод параметром с аннотацией `@RequestHeader`.

Для примера посмотрим на фрагмент кода:

```
@RestController
public class Places {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/classes/Place", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"X-Parse-Application-Id", "X-Parse-REST-API-Key"})
    public String getting(@RequestHeader("id") String id, @RequestHeader("key") String key){

        return "getting";
    }
}
```

Объявлен контроллер `Places` c одним методом `getting()`. Этот метод будет вызван, если пользователь обратится HTTP-методом `GET` по URL вида `http://ваш_сервер/ваш_путь_развертывания/classes/Place` и при этом передаст HTTP заголовки `X-Parse-Application-Id` и `X-Parse-REST-API-Key`.

---

Если вы хотите из Spring MVC приложения подключиться к другому REST-сервису посмотрите на RestTemplate. Для вашего случая это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("X-Parse-Application-Id", myAppId);
headers.set("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", myAppSecret);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Place", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Я понял. А есть ли возможность тогда штатными средствами Spring-a подключиться к другому серверу. Или тогда необходимо пользоваться сторонними библиотеками или методом doGet в сервлетах, например?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Это как раз то что мне нужно))